# Optimize nested loops in Ruby

Tags: ruby, optimization, nested-loops

In Ruby I have three nested loops:

```
array.each do |a|
  array.each do |b|
    array.each do |c|
      puts a * b * c
    end
  end
end
```

How can I optimize this code, if the number of nested loops can be increased to 5-10 and more iterations?

Example:

```
array.each do |a|
  array.each do |b|
    array.each do |c|
       array.each do |d|
         array.each do |e|
           array.each do |f|
             puts a * b * c * d * e * f
           end
         end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad english (I'm russian).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
array.repeated_combination(array.size).each do |combination| 
  puts combination.reduce(:*)
end
```

[`Array#repeated_combination`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-repeated_combination) returns an enumerator that yields all possible combinations.

Because this method generates all combinations before printing any output is might take a while depending on the size of the array. Keep in mind that the number of possible combinations increases quite fast: `O(nⁿ)` with `n` being the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two other ways (though I prefer @spickermann's answer)

**#1**

```
array = [1,2,3]
n = 4
arr = array.product(*[array]*(n-1)).map { |arr| arr.reduce(:*) }
arr.size #=> 81 = arr.size**n
arr.each { |e| puts e }
1
2
3
2
4
6
3
6
9
...
54
27
54
81
```

If you just want to print the products, replace `map` with `each` and `arr.reduce(:*)` with `puts arr.reduce(:*)`.

**#2**

```
sz = array.size
(0...sz**n).map { |i| i.to_s(sz)
                       .rjust(n,'_')
                       .chars
                       .reduce(1) { |t,e| t * (e=='_' ? 1 : array[e.to_i]) }
                }
```